# set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars). not having effect

Tags: prolog, flags, ciao-prolog

I am using Ciao prolog version 1.15.

I tried

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

yes

?- current_prolog_flag(double_quotes,X).

X = chars ?

yes

?- X = "hello".

X = [104,101,108,108,111] ?
```

so it seems like setting this flag is not working because the codes are returned rather than characters, even though the flag is set. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem in Ciao 1.22.0. Also, trying to set the flag to either `codes` or `atom` fails.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue https://github.com/ciao-lang/ciao/issues/26

Comment: Oh lol that was you XD

Comment: Reported 2011-01-24 for 1.13.0-12829 as [#18](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/ciao-prolog/#18)...